# Can't create a form recognizer resource on my Azure instance

Tags: azure, resources, creation

team and other readers,

I was entitled today to test the new Forms Recognizer Beta.
Following the steps in the guide I ended up in the resource creation form which does not contain tarif and region infos.

[Tarif and region infos are blank the cotain no values to chose from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWRVw.png)

Any advise?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

Hans, 
In the Azure portal page,  you could search "form recognizer", then the "form recognizer (preview)" should show up,  and you could use that to create resources. this is a new behavior since the  V2.0 public preview release (Dec of 2019, after you posted your question).

You could give it a try.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25092689)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25092689)